# how to sketch the graph of $r=\theta$, $-7\leq \theta\leq 7$

Tags: calculus

I want to draw the graph about $r=\theta$ where $-7\leq \theta \leq 7.$ 
The examples I've seen on the internet and in books always draw the figure positive part, such as 
$\theta>2\pi$ or $\theta>0$.
Please help me.

Comment: A negative radius doesn't make much sense. So I would just consider $\theta=r>0$. What is the next problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you want to switch the direction of $r$ if $\theta$ is negative.

Wolfram Alpha does this and so it looks as follows:
[image: nice pic]